# Edit a single form data field in angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, put

I have a angular form data submitted on the server using post request, the form has 9 fields. While submitting these 9 fields I have submitted values for only 8 field using my form UI. 1 remaining field was sent as null. Now on a new component I have created a new form with just 1 field, here I want to send a put request to the same 9 fields form and update this 1 field only. I hope this question makes sense. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

If you send a PUT method, its more likely with an ID of the row, or any other unique field, so you can update only the 9 field with this query:

```
"UPDATE table SET field9 = value WHERE id = row_id"
```